# How to generate a valid include statement using C++ macro pre-processor?

Tags: c++, macros, include, c-preprocessor

Best practices aside, is it possible to craft a **C++ pre-processor macro** that generates a valid `#include` statement that will later result in a file being included?

**Example**

```
#define MY_INCLUDE magic_goes_here

MY_INCLUDE
//This would be substituted with #include "somefile.h" and then later evaluated to include that file
```

**Use Case**

Since you might be wondering, here is my use case:

I want to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and only specify the OpenGL version and profile to use **ONCE** in my code. Unfortunately my platform (Qt5) does not make it possible to specify OpenGL version and profile as variables and so I resort to macros to ensure that the right classes are overloaded, that the right parameters are passed etc for all the boilerplate code necessary to set up OpenGL in Qt5.

However one last bit of headache remains:

```
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core>
```

In this case I would like to substitute the `4`, the `0` and the `Core` with macros.

So how can I do this?

Comment: You cannot. :( ...

Comment: Actually just minutes after posting this I did it! but only for "" and not <>

Comment: While you can not as such, you can isolate that troubled include in a header file of your own (say `ogl-in-use.h`) and use that all over you code. If you ever need to replace the version with another one, there's a single place to adjust

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [__has_include](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) before including a particular header.
This will allow you to feature test based on the availability of headers.

Example:

```
#if __has_include(<QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core>)
#  include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core>
#  define using_GL_4 1
#elif __has_include(<QOpenGLFunctions_3_0_Core>)
#  include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_0_Core>
#  define using_GL_3 1
#endif
```

You can then use your defined macros to know what version of GL has been included.

If you want to include files conditionally based on other macros,  you are going to have no choice but to account for every condition and use `#if/#elif` chains.  You can't build a header name and include it during preprocessing.

Comment: Is this standard in any way?